# Intersection of $\ell_p$

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\ell_p$ be defined as usual then what can be said about the intersection of $\ell_p$ spaces for i.e. $$\,\,\cap_{p=1}^{\infty}\ell_p\,\,$$

Comment: Well, we have $l_p \subset l_q$ for all $1\le p \le q$.